# Remove padding from PopupMenuItem (overflow menu)

Tags: dart, flutter

How to remove this 16 dp of padding from the `PopupMenuItem`? 
[image]

This is my list of `PopupMenuItem`

```
PopupMenuItem(
  child: Text("Hello"),
  value: 0,
),
PopupMenuItem(
  child: Text("Remove padding"),
  value: 1,
),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like it but this is the only solution that worked for me. I had to edit non project files (`PopupMenuItem` class)

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.enabled ? handleTap : null,
      child: Container(
        height: widget.height,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _kMenuHorizontalPadding), // setting this to 0 worked 
        child: item,
      ),
    );
```

PS: I hope someone will come up with better answer. And I will be glad to accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: In file popup_menu.dart there is hardcoded constants. `_kMenuHorizontalPadding` sets horizontal paddings, `_kBaselineOffsetFromBottom` and `_kMenuVerticalPadding` - vertical. So you can't change this padding. You have only two ways - either edit this file, as you've written, or copy source code from this file to your project and customize it as you need

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Yes, seems like that is the way to go. Do you also know how to change the width of `PopupMenuItem`?

Comment: Using extension in flutter can we do this modification?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you try to build your application in any other environment that doesn't contain your changes, it will not behave as expected at all. You should **never** edit the Flutter library. You would be better off creating your own subclass of `PopupMenuItem` in your project, that behaves as you want.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if flutter did not have the height property on PopupMenuItem before, but now it [does](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuItem/height.html). And setting it to zero removes that vertical padding.

```
PopupMenuButton(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, itemBuilder: (context) => [
  PopupMenuItem(height: 0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Text('World')),
  PopupMenuItem(height: 0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Text('Of')),
  PopupMenuItem(height: 0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Text('Warcraft'))
])
```

The above code sample removes all sorts of padding from menu items.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In my case I had to remove the fixed padding of 8 which moves all my components to the side and is not nice. For this I have created a workaround that works in my case. As I am working on a Row, this was enough for me:

```
ConstrainedBox constrainedBoxPopup =  new ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: new BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: 30.0,
        maxWidth: 30.0,
     ),
      child: popupMenuButton,
  );
```

As you can see I have forced a maximum height and width in a ConstrainedBox. In fact, the padding has no effect on it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your PopupMenuItems should be within a [PopupMenuButton widget which has a padding property set to 8dp by default](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html). Try changing that value to what you want.

Comment: Sorry but `PopupMenuButton`'s `padding` is only for itself not for its children.

Comment: Ah my bad. I guess you could create your own PopupMenuItem using a GestureDetector widget with a Text widget as it's child as it seems you can't change the PopupMenuItem's padding?

Comment: See my answer. It's ugly but doesn't require much efforts like creating my own class and overriding stuffs.